# how to pass a variable from a function to another within the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable that its value increase by one in "some function", I want to pass it to "another function" with last value this variable have reached !! knowing that this variable is in the middle of "some function" and "some function" reaturn some value 
both of functions belongs to the same class
I hope you understand me well :)
this is my code

```
class myClass:
      counter = 0
      def someFunction():
          #here is some codes
          string = "my string"
          globale counter
          for i in range(0, len(string))
              counter += 1
          return string

      def anotherFunction():
          return counter
```

Comment: Python parameter passing passes objects, not variables. You can't pass variables around. Also, there doesn't seem to be any reason to use a class here. This isn't Java; you don't need to shove everything into a class.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can approach this problem:

1. Return it in `someFunction()`:

```
class myClass:
      counter = 0
      def someFunction(self, counter):
          #here is some codes
          string = "my string"
          for i in range(0, len(string))
              counter += 1
          return string, counter

      def anotherFunction(self):
          return someFunction()[1]
```

2. Make it an instance or a class variable (I'm showing the former):

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
          self.counter = 0
    def someFunction(self):
          #here is some codes
          string = "my string"
          for i in range(0, len(string))
              self.counter += 1
          return string

      def anotherFunction(self):
          return self.counter
```

3. Use the `global` keyword to make a global variable. Don't do this.

Comment: thanks sir Alec Alameddine ,  when  I did the first solution that you've given the returned value in "another function" when I call it still  zero , I want it to be the last value the "counter" have reached in "for" loop

Comment: I added it in as an argument. Does it work now? Also, does solution 2 work?